# HTML5 - Use Video or Audio without Source for Control?

Tags: html, video, html5-video

Is there a way to use the controls and seek bar for `<video>` and `<audio>` without a source?

I want to use the control and subscribe to `timeupdate`.

Is there a way to generate a blank video or audio of a specific length?

Comment: http://mediaelementjs.com/ might be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can not set a `duration` of a video. See this reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#media-controllers

It is a readonly property, what you can read and set is the `currentTime`, which is the time where the video currently is.